# Switching activities on lockscreen shows lockscreen

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

So I'm making an app for my company, for a android tablet to be used like a "kiosk". Users should only be able to use this one app, and be able to do nothing else on the tablet.

I've found a solution by using WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED on the activities. However, when I switch to another activity in my app, the leaving activity fades out, shows the lock screen quickly and then the next activity appears.

I'm guessing that this is because the FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED is in onCreate(), as opposed to earlier in the Activity creation process.

Is there anywhere else I can put this flag, or any other way to prevent the lockscreen to be shown between activities? It's not a huge issue, but it is a poor user experience.

It is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 Running ICS 4.0.3.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, in all but one of the activities I try to open. I will try to figure out what is different between this one activity and the others, but currently I have no idea. The LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED is always placed in the oncreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to best fix this by using `Fragments` and using `FragmentManager` to swap out the fragments in the activity, so the lockscreen was never shown, since I never left the activity. The android developer guide has a good example for this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html